# Is it possible to make a less-than greater-than ordering relationship between enum values using comparison operator in c++20

Tags: c++, enums, c++20, spaceship-operator, partial-ordering

If we have an enum class like this

```cpp
enum class alpha{ a, b, c, d};
```

Is it possible to implement an operator that establishes an ordering relationship between the letters in the alphabet such that

```cpp
enum class alpha{ a, b, c, d};

constexpr auto operator <=> (alpha lhs, alpha rhs)
{ 
//how do we achieve this? 
};

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(alphabet, allows_ordering_comparison) 
{
    EXPECT_TRUE(alpha::a < alpha::b);
}
```

a less than comparison would evaluate to true. My mediocre understanding of this is that enum is a partial ordering. apologies for errors in the code. consider the question instead

Comment: In case anyone missed this, `enum class alpha{ a, b, c, d };` gives `alpha::a` the value 0, `alpha::b` the value 1, `alpha::c` the value 2, and `alpha::d` the value 3.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to do anything. The language provides a `<=>` for you that does the right thing already (assuming your enumerators are in order):

```cpp
enum class alpha{ a, b, c, d};

static_assert(alpha::a < alpha::b);
static_assert(alpha::a <=> alpha::b < 0);
```

---

If you really wanted to, for whatever reason, you could manually provide one that does the same thing that the language does for you: compare the underlying values:

```cpp
constexpr auto operator<=>(alpha lhs, alpha rhs)
{
    using T = std::underlying_type_t<alpha>;
    return T(lhs) <=> T(rhs);
}
```

Comment: "assuming your enumerators are in order" so ordering the members in the enum class would allow the compiler to generate the comparison for me. But what if the members are unordered eg. enum class  alpha { d, a, d, c} or we had  enum class temperature {mild, hot, cold}

Comment: It's not clear to me what should happen with a duplicate enumeration identifier like using `d` twice. But with `enum class temperature {mild, hot, cold};` you would have that `mild < hot`, `hot < cold`. The order is the order you list the identifiers, not alphabetical order of the names.

Comment: (Strictly speaking the order is based on the order of the underlying integral representation, which will by default be the order you list the enumeration identifiers but you can alter this behavior by specifying an underlying value yourself.)

Comment: @AaronChifwaloShavesha -- `enum class temperature { mild, hot, cold };`, `temperature::mild` has the value 0, `temperature::hot` has the value 1, and `temperature::cold` has the value 2.

Comment: @AaronChifwaloShavesha If you want them ordered, either order them or assign them values such that they're ordered.